# ArcGIS 10.5 ImportError: cannot import name multiarray with numpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, numpy

I've installed ArcGIS 10.5, and with it the numpy 1.9.3 library. However, I get the following error when I try to run any scripts with numpy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "U:\vickerss\TestNumpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy   

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs   

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *   

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx   

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray 

ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

Comment: After installing ArcGIS Desktop 10.5, what were the precise and detailed steps that you performed to install numpy 1.9.3?

Comment: @PolyGeo ArcGIS 10.5 ships with numpy 1.9.3 https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013224

Comment: @pascal have you manually installed any  other numpy?

Comment: No I did not, the bumpy version was shipped with the ArcGIS installation